# Looking for a key value inside a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to write a function that as soon as it receives a number it will inform the user if its already inside the list, like so:

```
TodoList=[{'id':5} ,{'id':3}  ,{'id':6}];
def AddItem(id):
     if id in TodoList:
          print('inside');
```

But I don't know how to search if its inside a a list of dictionaries, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to search for a key or for a value? Could you please add a sample output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create a list of all the values of the nested dictionaries and search them.

```
TodoList=[{'id':5} ,{'id':3}  ,{'id':6}];

def AddItem(id):
     values_TodoList = [i['id'] for i in TodoList]
     if id in values_TodoList:
          print('inside');
     else:
          print('not inside')

AddItem(5)
    inside

AddItem(10)
    not inside
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more efficient than the other answers since it will stop as soon as it finds a first match (and also supports the case where these dictionaries will have more key-value pairs):

```
TodoList = [{'id': 5}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 6}]

def AddItem(i):
    if any(d['id'] == i for d in TodoList):
        print('inside')

AddItem(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
TodoList=[{'id':5} ,{'id':3}  ,{'id':6}];
def AddItem(i):
     if any(i in d for d in TodoList):
          print('inside')
```

As a side-note do not use id as a variable name it shadows the built-in function [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id). If you want to search for a given value inside the dictionaries this will do as suggested by @DeepSpace:

```
def AddItem(i):
    if any(i in d.values() for d in TodoList):
        print('inside')


AddItem(5)
```

**Output**

```
inside
```

Comment: I guess the downvote is because your answer doesn't work. `i in d` will check if the id exists among the dict keys, not values.

Comment: Well the question says looking for a 'key' value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the safe dictionary method get(). 
Here is how you can solve this...

```
TodoList=[{'id':5} ,{'id':3}  ,{'id':6}];
def AddItem(id):
     values = [i.get('id') for i in TodoList]
     if id in values:
         return True
     return False

AddItem(2)
[OUT]: False

AddItem(3)
[Out]: True
```